# Can't add custom class to list

Tags: apex, list, wrapper-class

I have custom Wrapper class

```
public without sharing class OppProdWrapper {
    public String Name;
    public Decimal UnitPrice;
    public Decimal TotalPrice;
       
    public OppProdWrapper(String Name, Decimal UnitPrice, Decimal TotalPrice) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.UnitPrice = UnitPrice;
        this.TotalPrice = TotalPrice;
    }
}
```

And I use it in controller to get related fields and return to lwc.

```
        List<OppProdWrapper> oppProdWrappers = new List<OppProdWrapper>();
        for (OpportunityLineItem oppProd : oppProds) {
            OppProdWrapper wrapper = new OppProdWrapper(
                oppProd.Product2.Name,
                oppProd.UnitPrice,
                oppProd.TotalPrice
            );
            oppProdWrappers.add(wrapper);
        }
```

I start debug and see that all needed fields receive data but when

```
oppProdWrappers.add(wrapper);
```

execute, oppProdWrappers don't receive this data. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable in lightning component use @AuraEnabled Annotation  before the variable name.

*Example*

```
public class WrapperAccount {
    @auraenabled
    public string name{get;set;}
    @auraenabled
    public integer numberOfEmployees{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) It works!